# How to group by week (start is Thursday) using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by

I have a dataframe with data on a number of gained users by day. The dataframe:

```
users = {'Date':['13.02.2020', '15.02.2020', '19.02.2020', '20.02.2020', '23.02.2020', '26.02.2020'], 'Users_gain':['2', '1', '3', '1', '4', '5']}
df_users = pd.DataFrame(users)

Date    Users_gain
0   13.02.2020  2
1   15.02.2020  1
2   19.02.2020  3
3   20.02.2020  1
4   23.02.2020  4
5   26.02.2020  5
```

I need to group by week, where the start day is Thursday. So the result should look like this:

```
Date    Users_gain
0   13.02.2020 - 19.02.2020 6
1   20.02.2020 - 26.02.2020 10
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this question.

This is what I tried. But I don't know how to change the start date from Sunday to Thursday:

```
df_users.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W')).sum()
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Also there are only dates, where do you find the day.

Comment: df_users.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W')).sum() - This is what I tried. But I don't know how to change the start date from Sunday to Thursday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert columns to numbers and datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df_users['Users_gain'] = df_users['Users_gain'].astype(int)
df_users['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_users['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

Then aggregate by [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) or with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) by day `Wednesday`:

```
df_users = df_users.resample('W-Wed',on='Date')['Users_gain'].sum().reset_index()
#alternative
#df_users = df_users.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W-Wed')).sum().reset_index()
```

Last change format of datetimes with subtract 6 days and [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
s = (df_users['Date'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=6)).dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y-')
df_users['Date'] = s + df_users['Date'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

print (df_users)
                    Date  Users_gain
0  13.02.2020-19.02.2020           6
1  20.02.2020-26.02.2020          10
```